# Why C# round and SQL round functions yields different outputs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, rounding

I am using `ROUND` function from C# and SQL, and surprisingly both are yielding different results.

In SQL: `ROUND(1250.00, -2)` = 1300

In C# `ROUND 1250` with round and `precision = 2` = 1200

Has anyone came across this situation before?

Comment: which database server are you using??

Comment: It is all about the way the languages round numbers. Your SQL obviously rounds UP and c# rounds DOWN when you are bang in the middle. I suggest trying to use something other than ROUND. Ceiling in SQL rounds up, but without more information on what you are trying to do it really is impossible to advise on what to use.

Comment: To clarify, C# does not round numbers; the .NET BCL does.

Comment: I am using MSSQL server. Please help me to achieve the consistency in the results.

Comment: If you require exact results, don't round. If you are rounding with an expectation of exact results, one of these behaviors must not meet your expectations. If you don't know which, then you *aren't* expecting exact results. In other words, you don't seem to know what you want.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose - I am just trying to round up the given double value to the nearest 100. When I provide 2.5 it returns 3, but creating problem for 1250, differing in data.

Comment: I have written a custom function to achieve desired output. Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# uses banker's rounding by default, where when you're exactly on the .5 mark, it rounds to the nearest even number instead of always rounding up.

The remarks section of the msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx) describes this behavior.  Basically it's to reduce rounding errors when you accumulate a lot of rounded numbers together.

Comment: It's to reduce positive/negative bias and bias toward/away from zero when you accumulate rounded numbers that are _unevenly distributed_ between positive and negative values. Ref: Wikipedia article [Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Answer (score 4):

if you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx, you'll see that the default rounding is "round to even" (banker's rounding) where as  SQL Server 
appears to be using "standard" rounding

Update SQL Server  Either does Symmetric Arithmetic Rounding  or Symmetric Round Down (Fix) depending on arguments

how to solve the problem: Implement a custom rounding procedure: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q196652&ID=KB;EN-US;Q196652

Comment: The support link doesn't work anymore.
There is an implementation of Banker's rounding in SQL [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/sql-server-rounding-methods/)

Answer (score 2):

The difficult part in rounding is what to do with 5's in decimal.  They're actually exactly half-way, so they constitute a tie.  There's a good bit about [tie-breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking) in wikipedia's Rounding article.  Essentially, C# uses banker's rounding which rounds down when the last unrounded digit is even and up when it's odd.  This is in line with the IEEE standard.  SQL instead follows the "always round 5's up" rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter on Math.Round, `MidpointRounding`, to specify the way to round your numbers.

```
public enum MidpointRounding
{
    // When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward
    // the nearest even number.
    ToEven = 0,

    // When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward
    // the nearest number that is away from zero.
    AwayFromZero = 1,
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
int presicion = 2;
double valueToRound;

Math.Round(valueToRound / Math.Pow(10, precision), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    * Math.Pow(10, precision);
```

Comment: I tried with this parameter but no use. Still getting the same outcome :(