# Difference in Rounding In SQL and C#

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a value `7.25`. When this is rounded in `C#` with `Math.Round(7.25, 1)` it gives the value `7.2` and the same when rounded in `SQL` with `Round(7.25, 1)` gives the value as `7.3`.
I don't want to use mode - AwayFromZero in my code and want to keep it as `7.2`.
Is there anyway to achieve that in `SQL`?

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222307/why-c-sharp-round-and-sql-round-functions-yields-different-outputs) useful.

Answer (score 4):

[ROUND in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has a 3rd parameter

- zero = ROUND
- non-zero = truncate

So

```
SELECT
    Round(7.25, 1),
    Round(7.25, 1, 0),
    Round(7.25, 1, 1);
```

Gives

```
7.30    7.30    7.20
```

Note: The Math stuff in .net is not directly comparable to what SQL Server does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the third parameter in SQL.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7.25, 1, 1) RoundDown
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below. Also verify your other scenarios as well:

```
ROUND(7.25, 1, 1)
```